# Exclude files added/changed by a merge from hg status

Tags: mercurial

I have a repository `default` and a branch `mybranch`. Now I want to use `hg status` to show files which were added/changed in my branch but exclude files which were added/changed by a merge from `default`.

I tried

```
hg status --rev "branch('mybranch') and not merge()"
```

but this still contains files added by a merge. For testing I also tried

```
hg log --rev "branch('mybranch') and not merge()"
```

which works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you doing this in the middle of a merge commit? ie you have merged but not yet committed?

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs No, everything's commited at that point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may only be a partial answer, but it might help.

Option `--rev` does different things for `status` and `log` commands.

For [`status`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/status):

- `--rev REV [+]`       show **difference** from revision

For [`log`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/log):

- `-r   --rev REV [+]`  show **the specified** revision or revset

Note also that `status` does have an `-r` option but it is not a synonym for `--rev`.

So this at least explains why the two commands don't give you the results you expected.

Oddly, though the help page for `status` does not mention revsets, they do seem to be supported.

Comment: Even though my initial task isn't solved this _does_ answer my question as I'm now understanding why my approach didn't work. I'll try a different way than but this probably would be another question.

Comment: @BillTür glad it helped, and actually I'm glad I saw this question because it helped to clarify my own understanding as well :)